# iPhone sdk : Open Default Message tones list

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application , i want to set default system message tones for upcoming message settings. How can i open default device alertTones list.

I have tried following code, but its not returning any sound.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds"];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager
                                     enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                     options:0
                                     errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                         // Handle the error.
                                         // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                         return YES;
                                     }];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
    NSError *error;
    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
    if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
        // handle error
    }
    else if (! [isDirectory boolValue]) {
        [audioFileList addObject:url];
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked this link https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary. I think are you using this reference code and its working I have tested in the iPhone. I think you were testing in the iPhone Simulator. its not working in the simulator. So, Test in the Device its working fine[image: check the attach image which shows the list of the system sound]